# Who is the antecedent of 'him" in Isaiah 59:16?

Tags: isaiah, referent-identification, prophecy

Isaiah 59:16 KJV

> 16 And he saw that there was no man, and wondered that there was no intercessor:  therefore his arm brought salvation unto ***him***;  and his righteousness, it sustained ***him***

Who is the antecedent of him in the above text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous proper noun is "LORD" in v15b.  This forms the antecedent for the several verses that follow.  This includes the Isa 15:17 which provides the background for Eph 6:10-17 and the armour of God.

Ellicott comments on isa 19:15b:

> And the Lord saw it . . .--The verse at first suggests the thought
>   that what Jehovah saw were the sins thus described. The sequence of
>   thought, however, tends to the conclusion that the words are properly
>   the beginning of a new section, and that the supplied pronoun refers
>   to the repentance and confession of the people. It displeased
>   Him--literally, was evil in His eyes--that the penitents were still
>   subject to oppression, that they found no leader and deliverer, and
>   therefore He came, as it were, alone and unaided, to the rescue.
>   (Comp. Joel 2:17-19.)

In the next verse, v16, the Pulpit Commentary suggests:

> He saw that there was no man, and wondered that there was no
>   intercessor; i.e. God looked for some champion of the oppressed to
>   arise; it was to be expected under the circumstances. But, alas!
>   "there was no man." None stood up to resist the unrighteous and
>   protect the innocent; much less did any stand up to deliver Israel
>   from its heathen adversaries. When it is said that God "wondered" at
>   no champion appearing, we must understand the expression as an
>   anthropomorphism· Therefore his arm brought salvation unto him. As
>   them was no human champion, it became necessary that God should arise
>   in his own Person, and show himself. "His arm" and "his righteousness"
>   were enough; no human aid was needed, or could have added anything to
>   the resistless strength of his might (comp. Isaiah 63:5).